# How do I enable client-side caching for website project, using OutputCache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

I have an mvc website (not web application) and I am trying to enable client caching of pages.  I added the following attribute to my action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

When I look at the response, however, I'm seeing the following:

```
(Status-Line)       HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control       no-cache
Pragma              no-cache
Content-Type        text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Expires             -1
Date                Sat, 23 Jul 2011 17:09:45 GMT
Content-Length      9253
```

Is client-side caching not supported with website projects?  If it is, am I missing a configuration setting somewhere?  I have tried adding the @outputcache directive instead of the action attribute, but no luck there either.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is not a typical compiled mvc web application.  It is a website project that just references the mvc assemblies.